# Java throw exception custom message?

Tags: java

I know you can throw exceptions with custom messages using try-catch blocks, such as:

```
try {
   process...
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new IOException(..)
}
```

But if we have a method in a utility class like:

```
public void processFiles() throws IOException {
   ...
}
```

and then we pass into the service class like:

```
public void method() throws IOException {
   Response response = new Response()
   try {
      UtilityClass.processFiles()
   } catch (IOException e) {
      response.setMessage("Error processing files: " + e.getMessage());
      return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); 
   }
}
```

Is there a way to custom set the message from the utility class method `processFiles()` with its `throws IOException`, not using a try-catch block inside of that method?

Comment: You can catch the exception, then throw a new one with the new message and the old one as its cause.

Comment: I actually updated the question. I actually return a new ResponseEntity to my controller if an exception occurs, but in my console I want the reasoning for the exception.

Comment: You normally don't do this _on the console_ for a server application, since no one is watching it. Instead, you use a _logger_ such as slf4j, and then you'd say something like `log.error("couldn't process files", e)` (the logging frameworks all have signatures that accept an exception object, precisely because they understand you'll sometimes be logging error conditions).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what result you want. Do you want to set your own message on the IOException? Or do you want to not "throws IOException" in your `processFiles()` method and instead return a ResponseEntity?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- so i do this, but the error message is super broad, thats why i want to set a custom one

Comment: You'll note that in my example, you include a custom message in addition to the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the message, but you can create a new exception, with the desired message, and the same stack trace:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
  IOException ee = new IOException ("your message");
  ee.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
  throw ee;
}
```

Of course, this throws it as an IOException, rather than a subclass, if `e` is, say, a `FileNotFoundException`, so it doesn't *quite* achieve the same effect.